# R equivalent of endsWith to check against a list of strings

Tags: r, ends-with

I am attempting to check whether values in a column of a data frame end with any value from a predefined list of strings contained in a vector. I understand it is possible to check against a single string using endsWith, but I have not found a way of using this to check against a list of strings.

```
x <- c(" 2", " 3", " II", " III")
title <- c("a 2", "adbs", "ddig", "difo 3", "fgij III", "sdgoij")
endsWith(title, x)
```

I would not expect this code to do what I want it to, but what I am looking for is code that gives the following output using the above data.
TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option is to loop through the 'x', apply `endsWith` and `Reduce` the `list` of `vector`s to a single logical `vector`

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(x, function(y) endsWith(title, y)))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

Another option is `grepl` by `paste`ing the elements of 'x' to a single string with delimiter (`|`) and the metacharacter (`$`) at the end to specify the end of string

```
pat <- paste0("(", paste(x, collapse = "|"), ")$")
grepl(pat, title)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```